# Extinction of non-dominant species in generalized competitive Lotka-Volterra systems

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, constraints, population-dynamics

I am studying the [generalized $n$-species competitive Lotka-Volterra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Competitive_Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equations) system where populations of species $i$ are defined by the standard differential equation:

$$ \dot x_i = f_i(\mathbf{x}) := x_i \left( 1 - \sum_j a_{ij}x_j \right) $$

where all $a_{ij} \geq 0$ and $a_{ii}=1$. I know that any asymptotic behavior can be observed in general. However, I am wondering if there exist some constraints on the competition (or interaction) matrix $\mathbf{A}$ — with elements $a_{ij}$ — such that only a single species survives. More formally, do there exist characteristics of $\mathbf{A}$ such that there is only one fixed point $\mathbf{x}^\star_k$ wherein $x_k = 1$ and $\forall j\neq k, x_j=0$?

I have already observed that if $\mathbf{A}$ is a lower triangular matrix with all elements $1$ we obtain that only the dominant species $x_1$ will survive. We can also always reorder/relabel any system such that the species with index $1$ is the dominant one. It will the the only one to survive as we have in the fixed point $\mathbf{x}^\star$:
$$
f_1(\mathbf{x}^\star) = x_1^\star(1-x_1^\star) = 0, \;\text{thus}\; x_1^\star = 1,
$$
as we are interested in systems with $x_i(0) > 0$. This is just logistic growth of species $1$.
For subsequent species $x_2$ we obtain
$$
f_2(\mathbf{x}^\star) = x_2^\star(1-x_2^\star-x_1^\star) = 0, \;\text{thus}\; x_2^\star = 0,
$$
and the same holds for any other $i>2$.

Is this the only way that we can make only a single (dominant) species survive if all initial abundances are positive, $x_i>0$? Or are there perhaps more constraints we can place on the competition matrix $\mathbf{A}$ (or its elements $a_{ij}$) that ensure only a single species survives in the end?

Comment: Rough idea: it is well known that lotka--volterra system is equivalent to a replicator equation with some matrix $\bar A$. For this replicator equation is it sufficient to have a dominant strategy so that all other strategies will go extinct, in terms of lotka-volterra system this will be equivalent to the survival of only one species.

Comment: The [competition (or interaction) matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equation) is the matrix $\mathbf{A}$ with elements $a_{ij}$ that determine the competition rate as the influence of species $j$ on species $i$.

Comment: In the fixed point $dx^\star_i/dt=0$. When $\mathbf{A}$ is a lower triangular matrix with all non-zero elements equal to $1$, we have that $a_{11}=1$. Thus $dx_1/dt = x_1(1-x_1)$. Then, in the fixed point the abundance of species $1$ is given by $x_1^\star$, which solves the equation $x_1^\star(1-x_1^\star) = 0$, thus $x_1^\star=1$ (or $0$, but we are interested in systems with $x_i(0)>0$). The notation $\frac{dx_1}{dt}|_{\mathbf{x}^\star}$ is just the time derivative of $x_1$ evaluated at the fixed point $\mathbf{x}^\star = (x_1^\star, x_2^\star, \ldots, x_n^\star)$.

Comment: Ok, I have updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: The definition of $f_i$ clashes with the one on Wikipedia

Answer (score 2):

The simplest criteria I know that are sufficient to ensure that only a single species survives in any Lotka-Volterra system are that:

- the interaction matrix $(-A)$ is *Volterra-Lyapunov stable*, which means there is some diagonal matrix $D$ with positive diagonal for which $DA+A^TD$ is positive definite; and
- some single-species equilibrium is linearly (asymptotically) stable.

The Volterra-Lyapunov stability condition generally ensures that all solutions of the system approach some unique globally attracting equilibrium state, according to results in the 1998 book of Hofbauer & Sigmund, *Evolutionary Games and Population Dynamics*.

The linear stability condition is easy to check for a single-species state, as it just means $a_{kk}>0$ for all $k$ in this case. In other words, it means the diagonal elements of $A$ are positive (whether or not the system is competitive, with all nonnegative matrix entries).   The reason is that linear asymptotic stability implies the state is a local attractor; but the system has a unique global attractor due to the Volterra-Lyapunov stability property.

Without the Volterra-Lyapunov stability condition, it turns out that competitive Lotka-Volterra systems can admit quite large numbers of linearly stable steady states, at least $3^{N/3}$ for certain examples. Won Eui Hong and I published a [paper](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00285-021-01638-7) about this recently, also available on the [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.00611).

One has to be careful doing as @Artem suggests and carrying over stability results from replicator systems to Lotka-Volterra systems.  The known mappings do not ensure equivalence in every case. Moreover, the famous *evolutionarily stable state* criterion for replicator systems
neither implies nor is implied by linear asymptotic stability in the corresponding Lotka-Volterra system, in general. This is discussed in section 6 in our paper.  For single-species dominance in particular, though, I haven't thought about it.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I will have to look a bit deeper into the statements in order to check for a scheme that ensures only a single species survives. Please also check the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 1):

I have found some work by [M.L. Zeeman (1995)](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1995-123-01/S0002-9939-1995-1264833-2/) that pertains precisely to the question I was asking.
More specifically, in the paper it is proven that for an $n$-species competitive Lotka-Volterra model the following algebraic criteria on the parameters guarantee that all but one of the species is driven to extinction.
For a system given by
$$
\dot{x}_i = x_i\left(b_i- \sum_{j}^n a_{ij}x_j\right)
$$
the criteria are
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{b_j}{a_{jj}} < \frac{b_i}{a_{ij}} \quad \forall i<j, 
\quad \text{and} 
\quad \frac{b_j}{a_{jj}} > \frac{b_i}{a_{ij}} \quad \forall i>j.
\end{align}
$$
Which gives the fixed point $R_1 = (b_1/a_{11}, 0, 0, \ldots, 0)$ to be globally attracting on $\mathbb{R}^n_+$; i.e. the state with only positive abundance of species $x_1$ (after reordering if needed) will be globally attracting, thus only species $1$ will not go extinct.